# Practical meaning of omega potential

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

In statistical thermodynamics, the quantity omega potential is defined and is different for fermions, photons, phonons and other particles .

I have been understanding the derivations of omega potential for varied particles but I feel I am not really able to physically interpret what it actually is.

Is it similar to Gibbs energy? Since there are many energy parameters like internal energy, Gibbs free energy, energy of states - I am unable to understand what exactly omega potential signifies.

I tried to search over internet but I mostly found literature which was hard to decipher and get a quick answer.

Below is the omega potential for a fermion. What exactly does this equation provide us with?

\begin{align}
\Omega^* &= \sum_i\Omega_i^* \\
&= -KT\sum_i \ln\left[1+ \exp(\frac{\mu -\epsilon_i}{\mu T})\right]
\end{align}